# Is it grammatical to use "an even better " rather than "even better"?

Tags: grammar

I know this question is quite basic but right now I'm having a problem with it:

"Jimmy your english is bad. Try to speak in front of mirror or **an** even better option is to take english classes."

Is it grammatical to use "an" here?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it grammatical to use 'an' here?

Yes it is; in fact, it is necessary if you say *even better option,* but it's the noun *option* that makes the indefinite article *an* required.

If you were to instead say, *Try to speak in front of a mirror or, even better,  take English classes,* you would not need *an.* (in fact that would be incorrect).

Comment: Note that _mirror_ also requires an article.

Comment: Indeed it does. I copied and pasted the sentence;  I hadn't noticed that. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

"Try to speak in front of mirror, or an even better option is to take English classes." is fine.

However, there *is* an idiom using just the bare phrase "even better" which would not require using "a"/"an": "Try to speak in front of a mirror or, even better, take English classes."

Comment: It's not quite fine, because “speak in front of mirror” is missing an article.

Comment: It's funny how easy it is to miss an error like that!  The best way I've found to spot them anyway is to read the text you're proofreading aloud.  (Unfortunately, I don't remember to do this often enough, and I often miss my own errors...)

Comment: Yes, "a mirror". I was focusing too much on the "an" in question.

Answer (score -1):

English generally requires an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29) before a singular noun to express whether it is [definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Definite_article) or [indefinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Indefinite_article). Therefore, both *mirror* and *option* require articles in your example sentence:

> Try to speak in front of **a mirror,** or **an** even better **option** is to take English classes.

Modifiers like *even better* don't change whether you need an article. However, because they come between the article and the noun, they do determine whether you should use *a* or *an,* depending on whether the modifier starts with a consonant or vowel sound:

> **an option**
>   **a better** option
>   **an even** better option

Note that English does not use indefinite articles before plural nouns like *options,* [mass nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) like *water,* or some proper nouns. For example:

> Even better **options** are to take English classes or practice with native speakers.

Also, you only use articles with nouns. If you change the sentence so that *even better* modifies the whole main clause (instead of *option*), you no longer need an article:

> Even better, take English classes.

Comment: Downvoter: Any suggestion for improvement here?